# Number of digraphs with n vertices each of which has positive out- and in- degree or number of permutation-equivalence classes on $(0,1)$matrices

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, permutations

(sorry for my english just in case) Is there a value or at least some bound on a number of digraphs (loops are allowed, no parralel arcs) with n vertices where each vertex has both in- and out-degree of at least one?

It is clear that this question is equivalent through incidence matrix to the following one: we have an equivalence relation on the set of $n\times n$ $(0,1)$-matrices - we say that $A$ and $B$ are equal up-to a permutation if there is such permutation matrix $P$, that $PAP^T = B$. What is the number of equivalence classes on the set of matrices free of zero rows and columns?
Some lower bounds are welcome also

Comment: It seems the complement (ignoring the aspects of loops allowed) is counted in https://oeis.org/A002031 .
The case focusing only on the outdegree is https://oeis.org/A329228 .

Comment: The counts for such digraphs are now given in https://oeis.org/A367500